# Onde achar o caminho do banco de dados android?

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

```js
SQLiteDatabase BancoDados = null;
String NomeBanco = "Cadastro";

CriaBanco();

public void CriaBanco(){
        try{
            BancoDados = openOrCreateDatabase(NomeBanco, MODE_WORLD_READABLE, null);
            String SQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabCadastro11 ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT, imagePath TEXT ) ";
            BancoDados.execSQL(SQL);
            Criapasta();
            MensagemAlerta("Banco de Dados", "Banco Criado com Sucesso");
        }catch(Exception erro){
            MensagemAlerta("Erro Banco de Dados", "Não foi possivel criar o Banco" + erro);
        }
        finally {
            BancoDados.close();
        }
    }

    public void Criapasta() {
        File f = new File("/data/data/com.example.gabrielbonatto.oficial/databases/Cadastro"); //Já tentei o NomeBanco e o BancoDados
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/meu_banco_dump.db");
            while (true) {
                int i = fis.read();
                if (i != -1) {
                    fos.write(i);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            fos.flush();
            Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Li vários tutoriais para onde vai o arquivo db criado em uma aplicação Android, porém eu só acho usando na IDE Eclipse e não no Android Studio.

Alguém sabe para onde esse arquivo do banco de dados criado na aplicação vai ? Queria saber porque queria usar SQLite Browser para ver o meu banco

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está em:

```
//data/data/<SEU-APLICATIVO>/databases/<nome-do-seu-banco>
```

Coloque seu banco `<nome-do-seu-banco>` fora desta pasta usando um Gerenciador de Arquivos e renomeie a extensão para `.db3` para usar no `SQLiteExplorer`

Se estiver usando um emulador, use o [`DDMS`](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) para navegar nas pastas.

**Se desejar criar um "dump" do seu banco usando o Java no Android**

```
File f=new File("/data/data/<seu-app>/databases/<seu-database>.db3");
FileInputStream fis=null;
FileOutputStream fos=null;

try
{
  fis=new FileInputStream(f);
  fos=new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/meu_banco_dump.db");
  while(true)
  {
    int i=fis.read();
    if(i!=-1)
    {fos.write(i);}
    else
    {break;}
  }
  fos.flush();
  Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  Toast.makeText(this, "DB dump ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
finally
{
  try
  {
    fos.close();
    fis.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ioe)
  {}
}
```

Para saber se o arquivo do banco de dados existe:

```
File f = new File(...);
if(file.exists())
{      

}
```

Seu `manifest.xml` deve ter permissão de acesso ao cartão SD:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: onde eu poderia colocar o Dump ? logo após ter criado o banco ou antes?

Comment: @GabrielSantanaBonatto, a classe `new File()` acima não cria um banco, ela seta apenas o arquivo, portanto, o banco já deve existir antes de mover o dump

Comment: nessa parte /data/data/<seu-app>/databases/<seu-database>.db3 , <seu-app> = nome da aplicação ; <seu-database> = nome do banco ; /mnt/sdcard/meu_banco_dump.db = posso deixar assim ?

Comment: Opa, sim, basta substituir `<seu-app>` pelo nome da sua aplicação (como estiver no `manifest.xml` e `<seu-database>` pelo nome (literal) do seu banco.

Comment: então, eu criei o banco, mas só que esta dando "DB dump ERROR" , eu testei os dois SQLiteDatabase BancoDados = null e o  private String novoNome = null, vou editar meu código para vc ver

Comment: No `debug` você consegue saber se o arquivo existe? (atualiei minha resposta)

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/Oficial/databases/NomeBanco.db3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/Oficial/databases/BancoDados.db3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
(testei com os 2)

Comment: Sem colocar a extensão ".db3" também dá problema? Outra coisa, `Oficial` está correto? Lembre-se que deve ser o caminho do pacote seguido do nome da aplicação, ex.: `com.seusite.oficial`

Comment: retirei a extensão db3, o Oficial acho que estava incorreto, porque eu coloquei o pacote completo mas mesmo assim ainda da problema de diretório

Comment: Depois de muito sacrifício eu consegui colocar no /mnt/sdcard/meu_banco_dump.db , tinha que colocar o NomeBanco que era Cadastro e sem a extensão .db3...  e agora como eu faço para abrir ele com o SQLite Browser ?

Comment: Opa, como você fez? Me fale por favor, para eu atualizar a resposta. O `SQLite Browser` pode ser obtido em http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: File f=new File("/data/data/<seu-app>/databases/<seu-database>.db3"); tire o db3, e no <seu-database> é o nome do banco que é do tipo String na aplicação na hora de criar o banco, ou seja, não é a variavel que vc vai colocar, é o nome que vc já colocou na aplicação do seu banco
Ex: String NomeBanco = "Cadastro";
File f=new File("/data/data/com.example.gabrielbonatto.oficia/databases/Cadastro")

Comment: Mas agora como eu faço para selecionar o arquivo que esta lá no sdcard dentro do emulador?

Comment: O ideal é mover para o mesmo local do DB! Aí já seria um novo tópico hehe

Answer (score 5):

Para abrir essa opção no Android Studio siga os seguintes passos:

```
Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor
```

Lá dentro o caminho é o mesmo do DDMS tradicional do eclipse

```
/data/data/"seu package"/databases/"seu banco"
```

Lembrando que se você estiver utilizando um aparelho físico como "emulador" você deverá obter acesso de "super user" para conseguir visualizar seu Banco dentro do aparelho. Para obter esse acesso faça da seguinte maneira:

Navegar até a pasta .\sdk\platform-tools pelo ms-dos e executar o adb da seguinte forma.

```
.\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
```

List of devices attached
0123456789ABCDEF device

Este comando listará os dispositivos ativos e lhe dará o identificado do dispositivo, feito isto:

```
adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF shell
```

Depois acessar via super usuário:

```
$ su
# chmod 777 /data
# chmod 777 /data/data
# chmod 777 /data/data/br.com.dominio.projeto
# chmod 777 /data/data/br.com.dominio.projeto/databases
# chmod 777 /data/data/br.com.dominio.projeto/databases/banco.db
```

Após executar os comandos acima entre no DDMS selecione novamente o dispositivo e navegue ate

```
data/data/”seu projeto”/databases/banco.db
```

Comment: o caminho do DDMS só tem a pasta data e nada mais, não achei o nome do meu banco lá sendo q ele já esta criado

Comment: Você está utilizando um aparelho físico pra isso? se tiver você precisa liberar o acesso ao banco, dac maneira que expliquei

Comment: estou usando emulador  Bluestack

Comment: vou editar minha resposta colocando um print

Comment: A resposta do @FelipeDouradinho, se enquadra perfeitamente para você então, faça um dump para exportar para o SD seu BD.

Comment: é só jogar no código e ja era ?