# Aceder arquivo da Maquina Virtual pelo SQLite Browser

Tags: android, sqlite, emulador

O meu arquivo .db esta no SDCARD do emulador, só que como eu faço para abrir com o SQLite Browser esse arquivo que esta lá dentro ? Ou pegar esse arquivo que esta na pasta SDCARD e colocar na minha Area de trabalho ?
Exemplificando:
Meu arquivo está salvo na pasta SDCARD do meu emulador, eu quero de algum jeito que eu pegue esse arquivo e coloque em minha área de trabalho, eu não sei se existe uma pasta em minha maquina física compartilhada com a da maquina virtual (emulador), ou seja, eu so quero transferir de uma para a outra, para poder pegar esse arquivo e abrir pelo SQLite Browser, pois quando eu vou em Abrir Banco de Dados, ele abrirá da minha maquina física e não da virtual

Comment: Você precisa exportar seu banco via DDMS `/data/data/com.seuDominio/databases/ seu banco`

Comment: eu tirei do /data/data e coloquei no sdcard, só que agora eu queria abrir pelo SQLite Browser

Comment: Abre seu SQLite > open database > escolhe seu arquivo

Comment: ele esta no SDCARD da Maquina virtual, eu queria tirar da mv e colocar na minha maquina física, não achei uma pasta que fique os arquivos do SDCARD na maquina fisica

Comment: Essa VM, seria seu Emulador?

Comment: sim, o emulador é o bluestack

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71852/10315 essa resposta do @FelipeDouradinho te atende perfeitamente

Comment: ele atende a minha pergunta anterior perfeitamente, mas não essa, note que são perguntas diferentes

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25415/discussion-between-wellington-avelino-and-gabriel-santana-bonatto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exportar seu `banco.db` faça os seguintes passos:

> DDMS > File Explorer > data/data/seu dominio/databases

Após chegar até onde fica seu arquivo `banco.db` selecione o mesmo e clique em `pull a file from the device` o botão é um disquete no canto superior direito.

Depois é só selecionar onde deseja salvar seu arquivo e abrir com o `SQLite Browser`