# Banco de dados do app não exclui

Tags: android, sqlite

estou com um problema.

Eu criei um app e ele usa banco local sqlite, o problema é o seguinte, mesmo eu limpando os dados e desinstalando o app, quando eu instalo ele novamente, ele recupera os dados antigos que estavam no banco.

alguém pode me ajudar, já procurei em tudo para tentar achar algum lugar que poderia ficar salvo esse banco e não encontro.

Comment: Talvez porque os dados estão a ser criados/inseridos durante a criação do banco.

Comment: Este link nao poderia te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71846/onde-achar-o-caminho-do-banco-de-dados-android

Comment: Já verificou se o banco de dados pode ser acessado de outros IPs?
coloque % no cpanel de banco de dados remoto!
assim todos podem incluir e excluir

Comment: O banco é local no aparelho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifique o AndroidManifest.xml, dentro da tag application:

```
 android:allowBackup="false"
```

Basicamente ao deixar o allowBackup como "true", que é o padrão, alguns dados tem o backup feito automaticamente para sua conta do google drive.

Para mais informações: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html#Files

Comment: Kine deu certo, era um dos motivos, obrigado